# sorted list intersection on gpu

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

i know how to intersect two sorted lists on the CPU using an O(n+m) algorithm where n and m are the length of the 2 lists. However, is there a good algorithm for intersecting two lists on the GPU that avoids write conflicts. I am scared that while intersecting, two threads may try to write to the same output buffer resulting in conflict. I am not looking for a library. I want to know the basic idea + some code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you might not want your code to be tied to a library. However, I think Thrust has an algorithm that does exactly what you want, provided that you handle your list in a traditional C-array.

Have a look at `thrust::merge` here http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/group__merging.html

*-- edit --*

Having thought a little more on your question, intersecting two lists directly on the GPU seems very complex to write with CUDA.

The following code snippet is an alternative solution (a merge of my previous solution and of @jmsu's). This is an example how to intersect two integers lists stored in a decreasing order. The lists are stored in the device memory, but the computation cannot be performed within a kernel. Thus, you need to use it between kernel calls, if it is possible:

```
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <ostream>

int main() {

    int A_host[] = {11, 9, 5, 3};
    int B_host[] = {14, 12, 10, 5, 1};
    int sizeA = 4;
    int sizeB = 5;
    int sizeC = (sizeA < sizeB) ? sizeA : sizeB;

    int C_host[sizeC];

    int* A_device;
    int* B_device;
    int* C_device;

    cudaMalloc( (void**) &A_device, sizeof(int) * sizeA);
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &B_device, sizeof(int) * sizeB);
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &C_device, sizeof(int) * sizeC);

    cudaMemcpy( A_device, A_host, sizeof(int) * sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( B_device, B_host, sizeof(int) * sizeB, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset( C_device, 0, sizeof(int) * sizeC);

    // add an alias to thrust::device_ptr<int> to be more readable
    typedef thrust::device_ptr<int> ptrI;

    thrust::set_intersection(ptrI(A_device), ptrI(A_device + sizeA), ptrI(B_device), ptrI(B_device + sizeB), ptrI(C_device), thrust::greater<int>() );
    cudaMemcpy( C_host, C_device, sizeof(int) * sizeC, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    std::copy(C_host, C_host + sizeC, std::ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout, " ") );
}
```

Comment: Wont this do the intersection on the CPU, not GPU as both the input arrays are on the CPU, not GPU? I am pretty certain of this but want to double check

Comment: That's right but the size of C should be the minimum of the sizes of A and B.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper: what does ptrI(A_device) do? Is it the same as thrust::device_ptr<int>(A_device).

Comment: @Programmer: this is exactly the same, there is a `typedef` doing the alias two lines above. I was so lazy that I didn't not to copy/paste `thrust::device_ptr<int>` :)

Comment: @jHackTheRipper: your last print statement will not work as the actual number of elements in the final C_host may be less than sizeC. Thus, you would get trailing zero's

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:
If value A[i] exists in the array B, store it in C[i], otherwise C[i]:=DUMMY.

And then perform parallel array compaction?
There are tools to do exactly that - check [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~billeter/pub/pp/) for example - a library and a paper describing the algorithm used.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Thrust idea, as @jHackTheRipper said you don't need the whole of Thrust, you can use only what you need.

To do it with Thrust you can use the thrust::set_intersection

[http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/group_*set*_operations.html#ga17277fec1491c8a916c9908a5ae40807](http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/group__set__operations.html#ga17277fec1491c8a916c9908a5ae40807)

Example code from the Thrust documentation:

```
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
...
int A1[6] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
int A2[7] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5,  8, 13};

int result[7];

int *result_end = thrust::set_intersection(A1, A1 + 6, A2, A2 + 7, result);
// result is now {1, 3, 5}
```

To execute it on the GPU you can copy the arrays to device memory and use thrust::device_ptr or the better way is to use thrust::device_vector. These are compatible with STL vectors.

```
thrust::host_vector<int> h_list1;
thrust::host_vector<int> h_list2;
// insert code to populate the lists...

thrust::device_vector<int> d_list1 = h_list1; // copy list1 from host to device
thrust::device_vector<int> d_list2 = h_list2; // copy list2 from host to device

thrust::device_vector<int> d_result;

thrust::set_intersection(d_list1.begin(), d_list1.end(), d_list2.begin(), d_list2.end(), d_result.begin());

thrust::host_vector<int> h_result = d_result; // copy result from device to host
```

I haven't checked the code but it should be something close to this. The thrust website has great examples to get you started.

Comment: you cannot directly use device pointers in thrust's algorithms without having wrapped them in `thrust::device_ptr` before.

Comment: I recommended using device_vector and the example I gave reflects that. You can use those directly. The mention I did to thrust::device_pointer should have been thrust::device_ptr (changed it now) and I didn't go into details on how to use them nor used them in the example.

Comment: ok i was confused by `d_list2`: watch out, you're missing a `.begin()` after `d_list2` in the `thrust::set_intersection` call